# Simplest .NETapplication for a Tizen based TV to turn Bluetooth on or off

Tags: .net, bluetooth, tizen

Some Tizen based TVs have no interface to turn bluetooth off/on, as explained [here](https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/tv/disable-wireless-amp-bluetooth/td-p/625115). Accessing a menu that is only for use by authorized engineers is not an acceptable solution. Tizen OS allows accessing [bluetooth settings](http://tizen.org/privilege/bluetooth.admin) programatically.

> http://tizen.org/privilege/bluetooth
>
> Allows the application to change Bluetooth settings, such as turning Bluetooth on or off, setting the device name, and enabling or disabling AV remote control.
>
> Type: Native / Dotnet
> Level: Platform
> Privacy: No

I can't find a code snippet that is enough to do just this, anything I found is for Windows, and Tizen is Linux. Can you help me adapt the code below?

```
using System;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
using Windows.Devices.Radios;

class Program
{
    static async void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var radios = await Radio.GetRadiosAsync();
        var bluetooth = radios.FirstOrDefault(radio => radio.Kind == RadioKind.Bluetooth);
        
        if (bluetooth != null)
        {
            if (bluetooth.State == RadioState.On)
            {
                // Bluetooth is already enabled, turn it off
                await bluetooth.SetStateAsync(RadioState.Off);
                Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth turned off");
            }
            else
            {
                // Bluetooth is currently off, turn it on
                await bluetooth.SetStateAsync(RadioState.On);
                Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth turned on");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth is not available on this device");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Tizen supports .NET Application model, but, can't set the bluetooth setting by code. refer to https://docs.tizen.org/application/dotnet/guides/connectivity/bluetooth/

Comment: The Bluetooth on/off function affects basic operations of the TV such as the remote control, so it is not open to the third public API.
In addition, in case of TV products specifically, the use of setting gadgets for this purpose is also not supported, therefore, other than product manufacturers (Samsung TV), API that turns on/off the BT function cannot be used.

Comment: @DoHyunPyun In my case traditional infrared transmitter is more then enough to operate all TV functions. I don't buy Samsung justification for always-on bluetooth. I think Samsung simply uses it as digital fingerprinting.

Comment: Bluetooth, constantly in advertising mode, is also an indication if anyone is at home. For that reason alone it is a threat. If there are sane and capable people, they should jailbreak that functionality. Jailbreaking is legal.